# Use case of html5 data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with usage of the data attribute. When I add data using `data(key, value)` or remove data using `removeData`, it doesn't add/remove the data attribute to the html tag; im guessing it only does it in the inner javascript, not through tags.

This problem also leads me to another question as I am not very experienced with using data attributes. What are the use cases for data attributes? Is the following code, a "legal" usage of them?

```
<!---
    This code is supposed to animate between the sections when button is clicked.
    But it doesn't animate from second to third but just appends the next section (so, it becomes contacts+photo, instead of just contacts) because the data attribute is not added to the next section on the first click. I will try to create a fiddle and upload it to show a live result.

-->
<div data-ext="inf-slide">
    <section data-step="demographics" data-current="1">
        <!-- Content here -->
        <button data-next="contacts">
    </section>

    <section data-step="contacts">
        <!-- Content here -->
        <button data-next="photo">
    </section>

    <section data-step="photo">
        <!-- Content Here -->
        <button data-submit="/submit.php"> <!-- Ajax submit -->
    </section>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-ext="inf-slide"]').find('*[data-step]').hide();
    $('[data-ext="inf-slide"]').find('*[data-current]').show();
    $('[data-ext="inf-slide"]').find('*[data-next]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $next = $('[data-step='+$(this).data('next')+']');
        $current = $('*[data-current]').removeData('current');
        $next.data('current','1');
        $next.slideDown('fast');
        $current.slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

[EDIT] Fiddle: http://codepen.io/Gasimzada/pen/qGzdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data(key, value)` will store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements, it won't add or update the data-* attributes to the selected elements.

If you need to set the actual HTML data-* attribute, you'd need to use this:

```
$(this).attr("data-class_value", "new value");
```

Your use case is correct, you can use HTML5 data attributes to store any data.